# Show all date values on ggplot x axis - R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

In the following little dataset, I would like to plot date values on the x axis. I want all ticks of the dates present in the dataframe to be labelled. At the moment it is only labelling 3 random ticks. I could change the column to a factor, but having as a date means the x axis is spaced according to the time interval between points. So far the only answers I can find are for questions that want to show every month, or at least equally spaced time intervals. I just want to show the values in my dataset. Thank you

**Data:**

```
dput(melt)
structure(list(Sample = structure(c(16023, 16023, 16027, 16027, 
16031, 16031, 16035, 16035, 16038, 16038, 16044, 16044, 16023, 
16023, 16027, 16027, 16031, 16031, 16035, 16035, 16038, 16038, 
16044, 16044), class = "Date"), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("T1", "T5"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("20:5n-3", "20:4n-6"), class = "factor"), value = c(1.21879849498785, 
    1.88548990818282, 1.87990774775065, 1.25350826053539, 3.10352691206175, 
    1.18465888918519, 3.15176346709818, 1.82106970985234, 2.73680349074891, 
    1.58066166099405, 1.43967823968644, 1.51515884762159, 9.25194151767438, 
    9.23279864348857, 14.0535236345336, 9.06572816754405, 9.90634511302451, 
    10.0962470101343, 7.44314990623579, 12.7996706096935, 5.96573623304832, 
    8.070195431115, 2.57433899670204, 11.4388591839374)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code:**

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(melt, aes(x=Sample, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable))+
  facet_wrap(~Treatment)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

**Plot:**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. What is the problem doing `aes(x=factor(Sample)...` ?

Comment: @RonakShah the time intervals in the df are not evenly spaced. Most are 4 days apart, some are 3, one is 6. When in date format the space of the x axis reflects this. See in the plot how the distance between the second last point and last point is longer? When a factor they are all the same distance apart.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can supply `melt$Sample` as the breaks. You'll probably also want to rotate the axis labels to avoid overlap.

```
ggplot(melt, aes(x = Sample, y = value, colour = variable, group = variable)) +
  facet_wrap(~Treatment) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = melt$Sample) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

Comment: Beaten by 2 mins.  For a slightly different answer that does the same thing:
`scale_x_date(breaks = unique(melt$Sample)) + theme(axis.text.x  =  element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))`